# Am I to blame when my petty acts of selfishness have evil unforeseen consequences?

Tags: ethics, evil

Am I to blame when my petty acts of selfishness have evil unforeseen consequences, if some further bad consequences or other were foreseeable?

Suppose I am stalking a friend in the hope they will give me some money. Fortunately, they do not kill themselves. However, their mother is tipped over the edge by her child's confusion, and she kills herself. Am I morally responsible for the mother's death?

1. Who says I am *not at all* morally to blame?
2. What if it was not truly a selfish act, but for some greater good (that completely failed to materialise)?

Comment: so think "a lie out of self interest that destroyed the world": am i to blame?

Comment: I see what you mean, but you phrased it wrong. We need to have malicious intent toward every consequence of our action we are responsible for. Seems unlikely to me. If I shoot at someone, intending to wound them, and they die... @Futilitarian If I am a good marksman, perhaps I have diminished responsibility and it it is not murder. But I am surely to blame for their death

Comment: Your example describes foreseeable consequences, hence my first response.

Comment: Ah OK, that's great thanks @Futilitarian I'll have to think about whether in my hypothetical anyone could have known the evil would result. What if evil was foreseeable, just not its exact nature?

Comment: If a person performs an act knowing it will result in an evil, then they may be malicious and/or negligent. Alternatively, they might be acting to reduce a greater evil. A specific example would be useful.

Comment: The analogy with the narcotic is pretty much fine @Futilitarian I don't think in this instance the person could have reasonably been acting to reduce evil (unless perhaps we want to blame "the jews") But yeah, I agree, diminished responsibility but some. Any answers appreciated.

Comment: Oh. I see you made an edit I didn't notice until now. It may be informative to ask whether you would have performed the same action had you known the friend was pregnant.

Comment: Hm. I get what you mean @Futilitarian but, while it may be *relevant*, I don't think that completely dissolves responsibility  Mind you, moral blameworthiness may be more liberal than I thought, hah. Why should that person not be to blame if I was not hiding my pregnancy from anyone? I think they are somewhat to blame (along with their drug dealer, etc.), however virtuous they are to others

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/139690/discussion-between-futilitarian-and-who-cares).

Comment: I just want to know the answer, and have little need to chat about it @Futilitarian Thanks for helping me clarify the problem

Comment: I'm not sure how lying "to a friend to get them addicted to a dangerous narcotic" is a "small act of unkindness". If you want to use the drugs example, you should probably edit the question (or vice versa).

Comment: Next to a dead child @Futilitarian these things are relative. It's just withdrawal / rehab

Comment: Are you sure? The torment to the mother (and perhaps others as well), would seem far greater than that suffered by the foetus (in proportion to the stage of foetal development).

Comment: Why are we still having this discussion? I've gone through withdrawal, and I would not rather die, even before those couple of days are over. No-one mentioned a foetus. Please stop being pedantic. If you can think of a better example, state it @Futilitarian The idea about blameworthiness is clear

Comment: Your most likely not held morally responsible for the death of an unforeseeable death of a person only tangently related to your crime. However if it becomes a pattern that relatives of stalking victims tend to kill themselves, stalking might be associated with that and then you can no longer claim ignorance and that becomes foreseeable at which point you could also be blamed for taking that risk.

Comment: I get what you mean @haxor789 but I think we could use a philosopher :)

Comment: Per Aquinas you're likely not morally responsible for all those first order actions elicited as impulsive reflexive stimulations but morally responsible to fulfill or fail to fulfill those actions commanded through the love of God or per Kant via some universal categorical imperatives. Thus *after* you really understand this even an iota of your thoughts, speeches or petty actions you're morally responsible regardless there're unforeseen evil consequences beyond your ability, and this is exactly the reason there're so many different precepts and moral codes in Buddhism to avoid such cases...

Comment: Of course you may dislike intuitively the idea that even after the perfect divine command or universal categorical imperative realization or reception, one as a Dasein aka being-in-the-world is still subjective to the same various physical constraints and impulsions where Sartre termed the continual *struggle* for the serious after the reborn with its doomed pessimistic failure ultimately due to one's bad faith from the gaze, but one big leap towards the *completion* aka *pāramitā* in Eastern philosophy with the necessary required artistic skill. Practice, practice, practice makes perfect...

Comment: I think the study of law gives you perhaps better tools to analyze this fact pattern. Why?  Because your example is an intentional act. You have full scienter of doing wrong. Mens Rea.

Answer (score 3):

If you read Camus' L'etranger, he seems to be pointing at how acting authentically is not simply about choices in the moment, but also being reconciled with whatever the consequences of our actions are. They are after all always ultimately unknowable, we try to use our judgement to stack the deck, but the results will be whatever they are, and the key thing is living with ourselves afterwards.

Certainly you can go to consequentialist ethics, or utilitarian, or look at game-theory and transactions. But I would say the real issue is your conscience, because if that is clear even in prison you can feel in the right, and if it damns you even reassurances from everyone involved can't redeem you. Our conscience is deeply linked to how we see ourselves, to what kind of person we want to be. And that relates to our values, and what kind of society we want.

In the example, it seems like a very narrow interaction with the person 'that didn't kill themselves', which seems to imply they might have, they were in a bad place. Turns out their mother was on edge, maybe really worried about their child, suicidally worried. Whether or not you applying stressors to these people can be linked to the outcome, there was a missed opportunity to help, to support, to ask them what was going on. So, there was a shallow greedy interaction, and the world got more sad - losing their mother is going to be a lot tougher than being shaken down for money.

Blame, guilt, responsibility, these are in the eye of the beholder. But how you asign them defines what kind of person you are. And, you have to live with yourself more of the time than anyone else does. Who do you want to see in the mirror?

'The road to hell is paved with good intentions', is a proverb that points to problems with intending 'the greater good'. If we only think in a shallow way what to intend, we cheat ourselves, we make ourselves shallow. The nagging of our conscience, the still quiet voice, calls us to question ourselves, to integrate ourselves and act from that more integrated place. Wisdom isn't defined by an answer, but by someone listening to their whole self, until that is a deeper wiser self.

Comment: Great answer.  A bit in the vein of Sartre too, wherein we are “condemned to be free”.  Regardless of our intentions, if we choose to live authentically we are ultimately responsible for that which we experience - and therein lies both our power and our plight.

Comment: Right. I dislike the tone that my answer was wrong (given that it is well referenced etc.)